# How to reset a string in C

Tags: c, string

I have this string

`char currentString[212] = { 0 };`

and after I'm using it once, I want to reset it.

I tried many ways, such as:

```
for (int k = 0; k < strlen(currentString); k++)
{
    currentString[k] = '\0';
}
```

but it won't go over the loop more than once, and it give '\0' only to the first char, the rest remain the same.

and I also tried:

```
currentString[0] = '\0';
```

yet I get the same result.

any suggestions for what can I do?
thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? What's your outer problem? (The `strlen` function determines the length of a string based on its value. Calling `strlen` repeatedly while you're changing the string's value doesn't make much sense.) You can use `memset`, but there's a good chance you don't need to.

Comment: Don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminator* is what you write to the first position, effectively making the string "empty". The rest of the data after the null-terminator is unused and doesn't matter.

Comment: I want to have a fresh new String so  I could assign new character to. Obviously I prefer using the "currentString[0] = '\0';" method

Comment: How about just `strcpy(currentString, newContents)`? Why do you need to "reset" it? What is the use-case for that? What is the *real* problem that is supposed to solve?

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` will find the length by searching for the first occurrence of `\0`. So if you want to reset the whole array, you should change `strlen(currentString)` to `sizeof currentString`. However, do note that this will not work with pointers.

If you pass the array to a function, you cannot determine the size of the array afterwards, so this will not work:

```
void foo(char * arr) {
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof arr; k++) 
        arr[k] = '\0';
}
```

Instead you need to do like this:

```
void foo(char * arr, size_t size) {
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) 
        arr[k] = '\0';
}
```

But of course there's no reason to write custom functions for this when `memset` is available.

Comment: it works like a charm. thanks! but why doesnt this "currentString[0] = '\0';" works?

Comment: @Idan Depends on what you mean with "works". It does work. It will set the first character to zero, which means that it is a string of zero length.

Comment: my intention was to make all characters '\0'

Comment: @Idan you have special functions to do it.

Comment: @Idan Well, then it does not work because you're only instructing it to reset the first character. :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine `char currentString[] = "abc";` and then running you loop:

- `k = 0`
- initialy `strlen(currentString) = 3`, there are 3 characters before '\0' byte. the loop condition `k < strlen(currentString)` is true
- `k = 0` -> `currentString[0] = '\0'`
- `k++` -> `k = 1`
- then `strlen(currentString) = 0` (as the first byte of currentString is equal to '\0', there are no characters before '\0')
- the loop condition is false `k < strlen(currentString)` -> `1 < 0`

So the loop will always run only one time.

If you want to write only zero bytes to a memory region, use `memset`

```
 memset(currentString, 0, sizeof(currentString));
```

will set the memory region as pointed to by `currentString` pointer with `sizeof(currentString)` bytes to zeros.

Setting the first byte to zero:

```
 currentString[0] = '\0';
```

maybe considered enough to "clear a string".

Answer (score 1):

Setting the first byte to '\0' wont clear out the currentString.You may think that because ANSI C thinks that is a string terminator and if you print your string it will show empty.But if you check the second byte you will see the second char from your string. As other's said the best option to wipe out the string is:

```
memset(currentString, 0, sizeof(currentString));
```

And is way safer and faster.Also in ANSI C 0 and '\0' are the same.

Answer (score 0):

to zero the whole array

```
char arr[SOMESIZE];

/* ... */

memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
```

pointer - you need to know the size of the allocated memory as sizeof will return the size of the pointer itself only, not the referenced object;

```
char *p = malloc(SIZE);
/* ..... */
memset(p, 0 , SIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good decision to calculate anything again and again. Instead you should calculate the strlen() only once. 
That being said, in your case, doing so will solve the problem, as the reason it didn't work was that strlen() returned 0 right after the first round, since the length of the string became 0.

```
int n = strlen(currentString);
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
{
    currentString[k] = '\0';
}
```